# Why do dollar symbols not appear in a double-quoted PHP string?

Tags: php, explode

I am running some simple code from http://www.writephponline.com/

**Inputs**

```
$str  = "$Q$14";
$arr = explode("$", $str);

print_r($arr);
```

**Outputs**

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 14 )
```

My question is why array at index 0 is empty, shouldn't that be letter Q?

Please check the photo [image]

Comment: to achive this , your string would be like this :
`$str = "Q$14"; $arr = explode("$", $str);`
`print_r($arr);`

Comment: no the string is like what i said, as im getting it from db, so i can't change the order of the characters inside the string. thanks

Comment: Just replace the double quoted string `"$Q$14"` with a single quoted string `'$Q$14'` and PHP will stop trying to expand the variable `$Q` But because your string starts with a `$` you will always get occurance 0 as nothing

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly, you are correct i have to use single quote rather than double quote. thank you all

Comment: Just add a backslash before first $ dude and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the choice of the double quoted string type:

```
$Q = '$Q';
print_r(explode('$', "$Q$14"));
```

> Array ( [0] => [1] => Q [2] => 14 )

So what is happening in your code is a `"double quoted"` string replaces *valid* variable names to the value of them, where `$Q` is a valid name and `$14` is not because they may not start with a digit.

```
echo "$Q$14";
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: Q in ... on line ...
>   $14

So you're actually concatenating `null . '$14'` as variable `$Q` does not exist in *your* code and that value is `null` so the end value is: `$14`

If you would use a `'literal'` string, it works as expected:

```
echo '$Q$14';
```

> $Q$14

---

The other thing is that `explode()` splits the string into *2* pieces from the *first* delimiter found, so you will have a *left* and a *right* part. Any traditional delimiter found only causes 1 index to be appended. The string starts with a delimiter so the first array index is expected to be `null` because no value exists left of the first character.

```
print_r(explode('.', 'left.right'));
print_r(explode('.', 'left.middle.right'));
print_r(explode('$', '$Q$14'));
```

> Array ( [0] => left [1] => right )
>   Array ( [0] => left [1] => middle [2] => right )
>   Array ( [0] => [1] => Q [2] => 14 )

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve desired output with the same string you specified then try this one, add backslash(\) before first $

```
$str = "\$Q$14"; 
$arr = explode("$", $str);

print_r($arr);
```

I tried it and it worked.